# Correct syntax for get requests with rest-client

Tags: ruby, rest-client

Right now I can make a request as follows:

```
user = 'xxx'  
token = 'xxx'  
survey_id = 'xxx'  
response = RestClient.get "https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php?Request=getLegacyResponseData&User=#{user}&Token=#{token}&Version=2.0&SurveyID=#{survey_id}&Format=XML"
```

But there should be some nicer way to do this.  I've tried things like:

```
response = RestClient.get "https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php", :Request => 'getLegacyResponseData', :User => user, :Token => token, :Version => '2.0', :SurveyID => survey_id, :Format => 'XML'</code>
```

and variations thereof (strings instead of symbols for keys, including { and }, making the keys lower case, etc.) but none of the combinations I tried seemed to work.  What's the correct syntax here?

---

I tried the first suggestion below.  It didn't work.  For the record, this works:

```
surveys_from_api = RestClient.get "https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php?Request=getSurveys&User=#{user}&Token=#{token}&Version=#{version}&Format=JSON"
```

but this doesn't:

```
surveys_from_api = RestClient.get "https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php", :params => {:Request => 'getSurveys', :User => user, :Token => token, :Version => version, :Format => 'JSON'}
```

(where I've set *version = '2.0'*).

Answer (score 13):

You need to specify query strings parameters with the symbol :params. Otherwise they will be used as headers.

Example with params:

```
response = RestClient.get "https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php", :params => {:Request => 'getLegacyResponseData', :User => user, :Token => token, :Version => '2.0', :SurveyID => survey_id, :Format => 'XML'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  It didn't seem to work for me though.  You can see what I tried in the edit to my question above.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta That's strange. When I try the two request above I get two identical requests. I'm using mri 1.9.2-p318 and rest-client 1.6.7.

Comment: @Pafjo it seem the opposite. I can't insert a header parameters :-( always rest-client (1.7.2) seem considers all parmeters as "params"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Rest-Client (1.7.2)
I need to put both params and HTTP headers.

I solved with this syntax:

```
params = {id: id, device: device, status: status}
headers = {myheader: "giorgio"}

RestClient.put url, params, headers
```

I hate RestClient :-)

Answer (score 2):

In [rest-client api docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.6.3/RestClient/Request#initialize-instance_method) I see that `headers` is a `Hash` and if you want to provide both - headers and params, then you need to use a `:params` key inside the `headers` Hash. e.g.

`headers = { h1 => v1, h2 => v2, :params => {my params} }`

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is `URI.encode_www_form()` method.

```
uri = URI("https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php")
request_params = {
  Request: 'getLegacyResponseData',
  ...
}
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(request_params)
response = RestClient.get(uri.to_s)
```